# How copy ssh key to authorized_keys using php shell_exec?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2, php

I am trying to copy/paste an ssh key into authorized_keys file on an Ubuntu ec2 instance from a php script that runs shell_exec command.

I get permissions denied error. It's bout www-data user not having access to root permissions. But if I do that then it's a potential security threat and I am not sure of a workable solution..

I looked up online but I couldn't find any satisfactory results. Is there a way to make it work from php? Or how else can I do it?

EDIT:

The user is www-data.

PHP SCRIPT:

```
$out = shell_exec('sh /var/www/html/updatekey.sh '.$PUBKEY.' 2>&1');
```

Updatekey.sh SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkey="${1}";
authpath="/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys";
copykey=`grep -qF -- "$pkey" "$authpath" || echo "$pkey" >> "$authpath"`
echo $copykey
```

I am sending the public key to PHP script for adding in the authorzied_keys file because when I run this command:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /PATH/TO/PUBLIC/KEY USER@SERVER
```

I get permissions denied error. And now I am getting the same error in PHP script as well.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us what command you are running. Please [edit] your question and give us a _minimal_ example of your PHP script that reproduces the problem. Also tell us what user is running the php script and to which user's authorized_keys file you need to copy the key. Finally, you could also explain why you are trying to do this manually instead of running `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: Hey sorry. Just mentioned the code and reason for not using ssh-copy-id.

Comment: So you are trying to copy a key as the user `www-data` but which user's `authorized_keys` file are you trying to edit? Is it `www-data`'s or someone else's? If you're getting a permission denied error, then it's probably someone else's.

Comment: authorize_keys is owned by ubuntu/root user. And www-data is getting permissions denied because of that.. But if I give www-data the writing permissions then it becomes a security issue..

Comment: No, of course you don't give writing permissions! Not only is that a security issue (which is irrelevant, you already have a _huge_ security issue if you are allowing root to ssh!), it will also break ssh. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). You might want to ask a new question and explain what you are trying to do. You should not be attempting to edit other users' `authorized_keys` files, and you should not be allowing ssh as root. There are deeper problems here, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make it work from php?

Not really.

> How copy ssh key to authorized_keys using php shell_exec?

We do things like this in 2 steps:

- Have PHP store the key into a file on the server.
- Have a cron script pick up the file with then key and do the update.

The cron script runs as root so is capable of doing the update.

Comment: Yes. This might work I think. Can you point me in the right direction on how to build this cron job for picking up the file whenever needed?